# geoJSON location/geometry instance

Tags: geojson

I have a JSON file describing a business and the location is specified in GEOJSON. Without using `FEATURE`, I just want to specify that the location is always a GEOJSON geometry. So for the following instance do I need to use the phrase `"geometry"`? or Can I use any phrase such as `"GeometryInstance"` or `"InstanceLocation"` instead of the phrase `"geometry"`?

```
"geometry":{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              143.6033048818323,
              -38.76987023813212
            ],
            [
              143.605236072323,
              -38.76966947968941
            ],
            [
              143.60497858025758,
              -38.76839799643248
            ],
            [
              143.6029830167505,
              -38.768615488596204
            ],
            [
              143.6033048818323,
              -38.76987023813212
            ]
          ]
        ]}
```

Comment: geojson has a [defined specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946). You can test the validity of your geojson at [geojsonlint.com](http://geojsonlint.com/)

Comment: This seems to be valid to me, but geojsonlint says Line 1: "type" member required.

Comment: Therefore it's not valid. If you're going to use a `"geometry":{}` element, it HAS to be part of a `"feature"`.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot